# Custom directives and routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm quite new to AngularJS and Javascript as well, but I have managed to put together a custom camera directive that works the way I want it to. It let me choose camera from a list of available cameras, take snapshots, shows the picture taken and has buttons for saving a picture or dismiss it. The problem is that when I add routing to the app nothing happens any more when clicking the buttons. So my question is how do I get this directive to work as before when using routing with the app?

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('camera', function () {
return {
    template: '\
    <div ng-show="showVideo">\
        <div class="select">\
            <label for="videoSource">Video source: </label><select id="videoSource"></select>\
        </div>\
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>\
        <button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>\
    </div>\
    <div ng-show="showSnap">\
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>\
        <button id="save">Save Photo</button>\
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>\
    </div>',
    link: function ($scope) {

        $scope.showVideo = true;
        $scope.showSnap = false;

        var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
        var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        function gotSources(sourceInfos) {
            for (var i = 0; i !== sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
                var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = sourceInfo.id;
                if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
                    option.text = sourceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
                    videoSelect.appendChild(option);
                } else {
                    console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === 'undefined') {
            alert('This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome Canary.');
        } else {
            MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
        }

        function successCallback(stream) {
            window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
            videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            videoElement.play();
        }

        function errorCallback(error){
            console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
        }

        function start(){
            if (!!window.stream) {
                videoElement.src = null;
                window.stream.stop();
            }
            var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
            var constraints = {
                audio: false,
                video: {
                    optional: [{sourceId: videoSource}]
                }
            };
            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

        videoSelect.onchange = start;

        start();

        // Take snapshot example

        // Put event listeners into place
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
            };

        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                $scope.showVideo = false;
                $scope.showSnap = true;
            });
        });

        // Save photo
        document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
                $scope.image = image.src;
                console.log($scope.image);
                $scope.showVideo = true;
                $scope.showSnap = false;
                //return image;
            });

        });
        document.getElementById("cancel").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.showVideo = true;
                $scope.showSnap = false;
            });
        });
    }, false);
    }
};
});
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('cameraApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider .when('/', {
             controller: 'CameraController',
             templateUrl: 'views/app.html'
         })
         .when('/login', {
             controller: 'LoginController',
             templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
         })
         .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);


app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $window) {
    console.log($window);
    console.log($scope);
});

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope) {

});

app.controller('CameraController', function($scope) {

});
```

And here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="cameraApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularCameraApp</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/">App</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: I'm working on a clean solution but in my opinion you don't need a custom directive here. It makes you use too much jQuery instead of clean AngularJS directives (ng-click, ng-repeat, ng-options etc...)

Comment: No errors from the js console. My theory was that it had something to with priority because ng-view has a priority of 1000, but that wasn't it. Now I'm thinking it has to do with binding somehow.. what are your thoughts?

Comment: You could try to modify your directive to use ng-click instead of addElementListener. There is too much jQuery for me to have some really good guess about what is happening

Comment: That sounds great Okazari! I wanted to do that myself, but I don't know angular well enough yet to pull it of. Care to share your findings? ;) I also wanted to use ng-click instead but didn't know how to rewrite the code to work the angular way.

Comment: I'm working on the solution, i'm new to MediaStream so it take a bit longer than expected. We should chat about that. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78878/talk-about-an-angular-issue

Comment: Absolutely, but I don't have enough reputation yet to chat, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it to work. I need to develop three point in my answer, The solution, The problem, The mistakes/Advices. I'll first put the solution then i'll edit to add the others parts. Please re-read my answer after updates.

**The solution**

First you can see this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rbMRcsPz6wbkA8T3pr8S)

I moved your click functions into $scope variables like this :

```
    $scope.snap = function() {
      console.log("coucou");
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      $scope.showVideo = false;
      $scope.showSnap = true;
    }


    // Save photo
    $scope.save = function() {
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
          $scope.image = image.src;
          console.log($scope.image);
          $scope.showVideo = true;
          $scope.showSnap = false;
    }
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $scope.showVideo = true;
      $scope.showSnap = false;
    }
```

**Outside** of window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){})

I added some ng-click on your elements to bind them to the function.

```
    <button ng-click="save()">Save Photo</button>
```

And that's pretty much all.

**The problem**

The question is now, why did you have this error only after using the routing ?

You have to know that using

```
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){})
```

isn't a good idea in AngularJS.

Angular will load a first page : index.html (in my plunker) with a div

```
 <ng-view></ng-view>
```

When the html file is fully loaded the function above will fire. But the page isn't actually totally build. Your DOM is actually fully loaded but angular will use its routing system to add the app.html (in my plunker) into the ng-view element.

When window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){}) ran for the first time the three button didn't exist. So the clicks events weren't added.

**Mistakes/Advices**

I saw a lot of things that shoudn't be done in angularJS. I'll show you what, and how it should be done.

**1 - Manipulating DOM**

In angular you don't need to manipulate DOM from the javascript. If you want to do so, keep in mind that all your needs can be achieve by using native angular directives.

In angular you shoudn't see this :

```
 document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click",
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
 videoSelect.appendChild(option);
 document.createElement('option');
```

Instead you should see this kind of directives :

```
 //To launch a function on a click/change/focus/blur etc...
 <div ng-click="myfunction()"></div>
 <input ng-model="myvar" ng-change="function()">
 etc...
```

You can find all your needs in this short [angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Hope it helped you.

**2 - Directives**

The purpose of a directive is to add behaviour to an element. In your usecase a directive is a good choice if you re-use it if you don't re-use you component it was not that useful to make a directive out of that. Also keep in mind that custom directive are false-friends. Most of the time you don't need them to do what you want in a clean way.

**3 - $apply**

In angular you just want to keep away of $apply() as much as you can. It can really kill perfomance in some case and you don't need it 90% of the time.

**4 - One clean way to do what you want**

I would have really love to show you this working in the plunker, but it required too much works to adapt your directive to the clean way. In this way you should put a lot of things into a CameraService (The functions to get the media streams, launch it, stop it etc...) and just a few bindings into your controller and your HTML for having the same result.

An alternative clean way would be to use a container-directive and some directives to add the behaviour you want on each elements. But that require some good knowledge in angularJS

I hope it helped you. If you any question feel free to ask.

EDIT : Answer to the question in comment

I added this to the directive. You can see it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rbMRcsPz6wbkA8T3pr8S?p=preview)

```
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
        if (!!window.stream) {
            videoElement.src = null;
            window.stream.stop();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would also have loved to see the directive the clean way, but it works now as it is, so thank you very much for taking the time to help out with this. Thanks also for your detailed answer and the tutorial link. I have one more question though; when I navigate away from the camera page the video stream should stop, is this easily done?

Comment: @aloqvist Actually if you're about to use routing into your application, you should use ui-router instead of the build in angular router. It offer a lot of extra-feature you may need. With this one you can register to a $stateChangeStart event in your controller (or your directe) to launch a function that "stop" the stream for exemple. you can read this interesting post http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/ . I didn't use that much the native routing system so you could maybe ask this on an other question.

Comment: @aloqvist Edited to add the answer of your question at the end

Comment: I have already written the app and it's working to my employers specification, the only thing I had left was the camera, so you really saved my neck! The built in routing in angular have served me well so far but I will definatley evaluate ui-router to see what benefits it could bring. I going to try to solve the 'stop camera issue' on my own first before raising a new question. Anyway, thanks again for your help!